# Quotient Group $(Z/13Z)^*/<3>$

Tags: quotient-group

Are there many ways to construct quotient group?

For example

Suppose

$(Z/13Z)^*=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$

$\langle 3 \rangle = \{1,3,9\} \mod 13$

then, what is $(Z/13Z)^*/\langle 3 \rangle?$

At least one coset is $\{1,3,9\}$. But, how can we divide $(Z/13Z)^*$?

My answer is $\{\{1,3,9\},\{5,2,6\},\{12,10,4\},\{8,11,7\}\} =\{\langle 3 \rangle,5\langle 3 \rangle, 5^2\langle 3 \rangle, 5^3\langle 3 \rangle  \} $.

But there exist another answer : $\{\{1,3,9\},\{2,6,5\},\{4,12,10\},\{8,11,7\}\}$

Which is correct?

Comment: What is the difference between $\{5,2,6\}$ and $\{2,6,5\}$?

Comment: i am not sure. Should I consider the order of element in each coset?

Comment: Not at all. These are the same sets and the same groups, the order doesn't matter.